# this._callback.apply is not a function ! Node js Mysql error

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

Controller Code

```
app.post('/savedata', function(req, res) {
var cope = req.body;
console.log("On server side");
console.log(cope.Client_ID);
var queries = 
connection.query('update lv_billing.client SET Client_ID = ?, Client_Name = ?,Status = ?,Updt_Time = ?,Updt_By = ?,Updt_ID = ?,Cluster = ? where Client_ID = ?',cope.Client_ID,cope.Client_Name,cope.Status,cope.Updt_Time,cope.Updt_By,cope.Updt_ID,cope.Cluster,cope.Client_ID, function(err,res){
if(err) throw err;
    console.log('Inserted!');
})
});
```

The above code is throwing the error "this._callback.apply" is not even a function. To set a little context. i m trying to update my table with the new values from the array. 'cope' is an array which holds values which needs to be updated.

Answer (score 4):

As @RugDealer mentioned, you should provide the callback function as the second or third argument. If you are using the mysql module you can alter your function like this:

```
    app.post('/savedata', function(req, res) {
      var cope = req.body;
      console.log("On server side");
      console.log(cope.Client_ID);
      var params = [cope.Client_ID, cope.Client_Name, cope.Status, cope.Updt_Time, cope.Updt_By, cope.Updt_ID, cope.Cluster, cope.Client_ID];
      var queries = 
      connection.query('update lv_billing.client SET Client_ID = ?,Client_Name = ?,Status = ?,Updt_Time = ?,Updt_By = ?,Updt_ID = ?,Cluster = ? where Client_ID = ?',params, function(err,res){
       if(err) throw err;
       console.log('Inserted!');
      });
    });
```

For more information checkout the source: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql

Answer (score 2):

```
var q = con.query('UPDATE table_Name SET wordstype_count = wordstype_count + ? Where user_id = ?', [data.keyCount , data.userId],function (err, result) {
                if (err) throw err;
              }
            );
```

use your parameter like this. this is working fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

You're callback is supposed to be your second parameter.

```
connection.query('query string here', callback_function_here);
```

Just concatenate your variables like so, otherwise they are considered as parameters:

```
'update lv_billing.client SET Client_ID = ' + cope.Client_ID + ' ... '
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which mysql driver you are using because you didn't say so or give any clues in the code you wrote.  With that said, I assume that the code should look more like this:

```
app.post('/savedata', function(req, res) {
  var cope = req.body;
  console.log("On server side");
  console.log(cope.Client_ID);
  var queries = connection.query('update lv_billing.client SET Client_ID = ' + cope.Client_ID + ', Client_Name = ' + cope.Client_Name + ' ,Status = ' + cope.Status + ' ,Updt_Time = ' + cope.Updt_Time + ',Updt_By = ' + cope.Updt_By + ',Updt_ID = ' + cope.Updt_ID + ',Cluster = ' + cope.Cluster + ' where Client_ID = ' + cope.Client_ID, function(err,res){
  if(err) throw err;
    console.log('Inserted!');
  })
});
```

Usually when you get an error saying something is not a function, it means that you are trying to use something as a function that is not a function.  My assumption is that you are using a library similar to this:

https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#performing-queries

Notice that the format for querying is like this:

```
.query(sqlString, callback)
```